# How to set values globally in android

Tags: android

How to set values globally so that i can access from any activity or fragment.

For eg : activity_login.java > user_id need to store globally so every time any section which depends on user_id, checking and pulling data from backend will be easy instead of passing through activity (intent)

Edit : 
i do need setter and getter from **fragment** or activtiy.

Comment: save it to shared preference or declare it public static in which class do you get.

Comment: Use shared preference to save user related data.

Comment: Or, maybe this one instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/how-to-declare-global-variables-in-android

Comment: You can declare your variable static and when you need to use define : yourclassname.younamevalue

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to store values globally so it can be access from any where in application all classes :

1. Declare public static variable but it's not preferable for long storage.
2. Use shared preferences - [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
3. Use database - [SQlite](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

You can use any of one above alternative to access globally values.

Comment: static variables must be used with care. The OS can remove an app from memory when the space is needed and the static variables are then typically not restored when the activity is activated again.

Comment: @Henry,If you need to load a bunch of stuff in memory, that's either a problem or it isn't

Comment: Exactly, that's why I said "use with care". For long term storage static variables are almost always the wrong approach.

Comment: @Henry,Thanks now you can see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sharedpreferences.its safe, Here's the example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Answer (score 0):

> Use sharedPreferences and access the values at any of your class

Put the below code at SamplePreferences.java

private static final String TOTALCOUNT = "total_count";

```
public static void setTotalCount(Context thisActivity, String id) {
    Editor editor = thisActivity.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(TOTALCOUNT, id);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getTotalCount(Context thisActivity) {
    SharedPreferences user_pref = thisActivity.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return user_pref.getString(TOTALCOUNT, "0");

}
```

> You can set the values from any of your class use below code

```
SamplePreferences.setTotalCount(thisContext, "2");
```

> Access that value using below code

```
SamplePreferences.getTotalCount(thisContext);
```